# Why does iOS Twitter app search engine work offline?

Tags: ios, api, twitter, offline

I'm building an iOS app related to Twitter and I need to know how do user search engine works. More specifically, I want to make my app show the usernames starting with a certain string. Just as when you're tweeting something and you start typing `@Jo` and below it appears `@JohnSmith, @JoshBennett, etc.` ordered by relevance.

In order to figure out how does this feature work, I thought that Twitter may have downloaded all my followers and following list, so that they can access it locally. But I found out that in my search results there appeared people that I don't actually follow but some of my followers follow them. So, does Twitter have downloaded all my followers and all my followers' followers?

In any case, what I want for my app is to only look for the users I follow but it's important to know how I am supposed to download these users information. Taking into account that these requests have a daily limit, what would the app do with a user with millions of followers?

I hope that some of you have faced this issue and can give me some advice. Thanks!